# Iterating with while loop instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ECMAScript 6 introduces generators, iterators and syntax sugar for iteration. Node.JS v0.11.4 with the flags

> `--harmony --use_strict --harmony_generators`

understands the following generator

```
function* fibonacci() {
  let previous = 0;
  let current = 1;

  while(true) {
    let temp = previous;
    previous = current;
    yield current = temp + current;
  }
}
```

I can then print the Fibonacci numbers less than 1000.

```
for(let value of fibonacci()) {
    if(value > 1000) { break; }
    console.log(value);
}
```

For this example a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop would be more natural, similar to

```
while(value of fibonacci() < 1000) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Can iteration of iterators be done with a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call a generator step by step using `next` function

```
var sequence = fibonacci();
var value;
while ((value = sequence.next()) < 1000) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

plus, maybe even a nicer solution would be something like:

```
function* fibonacci(limit){
  let previous = 0;
  let current = 1;

  while(previous + current < limit) {
    let temp = previous;
    previous = current;
    yield current = temp + current;
  }
}

for(let value of fibonacci(1000)) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: @Randomblue I think that's a mistake in the OPs question, not the answer.

Comment: @AaditMShah i thought so too, but Randomblue seems to be the OP so i am confused. What is the "*" supposed to do?

Comment: @fsw It's the [notation for generators](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-13.4).

Comment: @AaditMShah No, according to the specs `function*` marks a function as generator.

Comment: Oh. Lol. Why such weird syntax?

Comment: @AaditMShah The argument when the decision was made is that generators (and co-routines) are fundamentally different in behavior and that explicit notation needs to be provided. I'm not sure I agree by the way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So ES6 has both generators and coroutines? I still need to understand precisely how they are different.

Comment: @AaditMShah Generators _are_ co-routines. Coroutines are like subroutines that can return in the middle of the execution (like generators), every generator is a co-routine but not every co-routine is a generator.

Comment: OK, now I see that indeed ECMA specifies so and V8 requires "*". edited. wonder why mozilla ignored this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: @fsw Mozilla's current implementation of generators is a joke :) That's why. Honestly though, they just implemented generators (as well as `for... of` which _also_ isn't in the spec by the way) _before_ it was in the spec, that's why they do silly things like throwing an exception when you're done with iteration (like in python generators and unlike C# generators).

Comment: Correction to my last comment as it can't be modified anymore - apparently for... of loops are _back_ in the spec in addition to .forEach . Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 7):

There are two possible ways I'd go on about this, given other languages that support this behavior:

1)  One using Harmony proxies, which would let you doing meta-tables (kind of like in **lua**) and allow for lazy iterables. This would provide fhe following notation:

```
var arr = ...; // create the resource
for(var i=0;arr[i]<1000;i++){
    arr[i]; // consume fibonacci numbers
}
```

2) The second using a `take` function letting you consume an iterable with `.forEach` like in **C#** or **python**. Which would allow the following notation:

```
 takeWhile(fibGenerator,(item) => item<1000).forEach(... // consume with predicate
```

---

### First approach - using harmony proxies

Note... `for of` loops through objects. It does not guarantee order at all. You *can* however do something like the following to get the notion of a lazy iterate.

You have to run node both with the `--harmony_generators` and `--harmony_proxies` flags:

```
var arr = ...; // create an array and proxy it, use a generator internally
arr[50]; // will calculate the 50th fibonacci element and return it.
arr[100];// will calculate the 100th fibonacci element and return it.
for(var i=0;arr[i]<1000;i++){
   arr[i];//the i-th fibonacci number
}
```

It will only calculate numbers not fetched yet, this will allow you to use a simple `for` loop.

Here is how*:

```
var cache = [];
var handler = {
        get: (function(){
          function fibIterator(){
             var t=0,a=0,b=0;
             return function(){
                t=a;
                a+=b;
                b=t;
                return a;
             }
          }
          var iterator = fibIterator();
          return function (target, fibNumber) {
                if (name in cache) {
                    return cache[name];
                }
                while(iterator < fibNumber){
                    // update indexes. 
                }
           })()
        }
    };
var arr = Proxy.create(handler);
```

(Just don't expect it to be very fast)

*(using old proxy notation, since the new one isn't supported in node yet, will update once it gets support)

---

Side note, in JavaScript since functions can have internal state through closures, you don't even really need a generator

### Second approach, using an iterator `Take` function.

This is what you'd normally do in languages like C# for this use case.

```
function takeWhile(generating, predicate){
    var res = [],last;
    do{
        res.push(last=generating())
    }while(predicate(last));
    return res;
}
```

Then do something like

```
var res = takeWhile(fibIterator,function(item){
    return item<1000;
});
res.forEach(function(){ ...
```

Or by count:

```
function take(generating,numToTake){
    var res = [],num;
    do{
        res.push(last=generating())
    }while(num++ < numToTake);
    return res;
}

var res = take(fibIterator,1000);//first 1000 numbers
```

Comment: @Randomblue If you think that's helpful - sure. Which version do you like better? (So it gets to keep the vote count)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function *bar(){
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  return 4;
}

var value,
  g = bar();

while((value = g.next()).value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

```
//Object {value: 1, done: false}
//Object {value: 2, done: false}
//Object {value: 3, done: false}
//Object {value: 4, done: true}
```

Comment: Answering a 2 year old question that has accepted answers already, you might want to explain what solution brings to the table that wasn't there before. Maybe in a little paragraph?

Comment: maybe practice in stackoverflow

Comment: This one does **NOT** work. It's ending on values not done. insert a `yield 0` after `yield 2` and watch it fail. You probably want `while(!(value = g.next()).done){`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this by using the regular generator methods.

```
var fib = fibonacci(), value;
while( (value = fib.next()) < 1000 ) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Although I seem to prefer the `for...of` statement which takes care of handling those next calls and dealing with `StopIteration`(if the sequence is finite).